# Ajax form serialized data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following function in ajax:

```
    function update_row(ID,CODE,NAME,PRICE){
                $.ajax({
                url: "update-record.php",
                data: "ID="+ID,
                date: "CODE="+CODE,
                data: "NAME="+NAME,
                data: "PRICE="+PRICE,
                type: "post",
                success: function(result){
                    $('#prod2_'+ID).hide();
                }
            });         
    }
```

This should call the "update-record.php" which is the following:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$product_id = $_POST['ID'];
$product_code = $_POST['CODE'];
$product_name = $_POST['NAME'];
$product_price = $_POST['PRICE'];
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `products` SET `code`=$product_code,`name`=$product_name,`price`=$product_price WHERE 'id'=$product_id");
echo json_encode('Record deleted');
?>
```

and this is the buttom I am useing to call the ajax fuction:

```
'<div><input id=prod2_"'.$row['ID'].'" type=button name="click3" onclick="update_row('.$row['ID'].','.$row['code'].','.$row['name'].','.$row['price'].')" value="Hide"></div>';
```

This button should update the database record and also hide the "form" where i post the datas. Unfortunately it does nothing.

Any suggestions how to resolve the problem?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: There should only be one `data` property. Provide it as an object, eg `data: { id: ID, code: CODE, name: NAME, price: PRICE }`. After that check the console for errors. It should tell you if and why the request fails

Comment: Rory is right and you also have a date field... send us the browser console error (press F12 and search Console)

Comment: in the console i got the following error "deleteproduct.php:54 Uncaught ReferenceError: C18 is not defined" this "C18" is the first value that i would like to update

Comment: That's not how object literals work...

Comment: can you please tell me how should i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
'<div><input id="prod2_'.$row['ID'].'" type="button" name="click3" onclick="update_row(\''.$row['ID'].'\',\''.$row['code'].'\',\''.$row['name'].'\',\''.$row['price'].'\')" hidden="yes"></div>';
```

and change this

You need to connect mysql server

```
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

And connect to query

```
mysql_query($conn,"UPDATE products SET code='$product_code',name='$product_name',price='$product_price' WHERE id='$product_id'");
```

and change this

```
function update_row(ID,CODE,NAME,PRICE){
                var dataString = 'ID='+ ID + '&CODE=' + CODE + '&NAME=' + NAME + '&PRICE=' + PRICE;
                $.ajax({
                url: "rt.php",//Your php page code this is my test code
                data: dataString,
                type: "post",
                success: function(result){
                    $('#prod2_'+ID).hide();
                }
            });         
    }
```

Comment: Now it only hides the form, but unfortunately does not update the database

Comment: O i check them one seacond

Comment: Still nothing, and no error code in the console neither

Comment: I change them its now working. You need to connect mysql server

Comment: the connection already was made in "config.php" file, but i give it a try

Comment: You change them  `mysql_query($conn,"UPDATE products SET code='$product_code',name='$product_name',price='$product_price' WHERE id='$product_id'");`

Comment: You need to select your database name

Comment: I have a button for deleting records, that one works fine whit the "config.php" there must be some problem posting the datas correcly i think

Comment: You can send some example

Comment: about? what i want to update? and i found some comment on other sites that says to "serialize" the datas

Comment: Now check i solve them and this code is work properly

Comment: Do you send your site i check that

Comment: I post it as an answhere here on the page

Comment: found the problem... i do not sent propperly the datas to the update

Comment: Actualy it work propperly the problem is whit the data i want to send to the function, i always gets the default values and not the ones i want to update to

Comment: I think you contact me on facebook my facebook url is facebook.com/suman253. I solve your problem when i see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax data object is wrong. Please try this:

```
function update_row(ID, CODE, NAME, PRICE) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "update-record.php",
        data: "ID=" + ID+"&CODE=" + CODE+"&NAME=" + NAME + "&PRICE=" + PRICE,
        type: "post",
        success: function(result) {
            $('#prod2_' + ID).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
        function delete_row(ID){
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "remove-record.php",
                    data: "ID="+ID,
                    type: "post",
                    success: function(result){
                        $('#prod_'+ID).remove();
                    }
                });         
        }

        function show_row(ID){
                    $.ajax({
                    data: "ID="+ID,
                    type: "post",
                    success: function(result){
                        $('#prod2_'+ID).show();
                    }
                });         
        }


        function update_row(ID,CODE,NAME,PRICE){
                    var dataString = 'ID='+ ID + '&CODE=' + CODE + '&NAME=' + NAME + '&PRICE=' + PRICE;
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "update-record.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    type: "post",
                    success: function(result){
                    $('#prod2_'+ID).hide();
                    }
                });         
        }
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>    
    <div class="tittle"><b>Delete product</b></div>
    <?php include "menu.html"; ?>
    <div style = "margin:30px" align = "center">
            <form action="deleteproduct.php" method="post" >
            <fieldset>
                <?php
                    include 'config.php';
                    $aktiv=$_COOKIE['account_id'];
                    echo "<ul id='productlist'>
                    <li>
                    <div>Code</div>
                    <div>Name</div>
                    <div>Price</div>
                    </li>";

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products where updated_account_ID='$aktiv' order by ID";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<li id=prod_".$row['ID'].">";
                        echo '<div>' . $row['code'] . '</div>';
                        echo '<div>' . $row['name'] . '</div>';
                        echo '<div>' . $row['price'] . '</div>';
                        echo '<div><input type=button name="click" onclick="delete_row('.$row['ID'].')" value="Delete"></div>';
                        echo '<div><input type=button name="click2" onclick="show_row('.$row['ID'].')" value="Update"></div>';
                        echo "<li hidden id=prod2_".$row['ID'].">";
                        echo '<div><input type="text" value="'.$row['code'].'"</div>';
                        echo '<div><input type="text" value="'.$row['name'].'"</div>';
                        echo '<div><input type="text" value="'.$row['price'].'"</div>';
                        echo '<div><input  type="button" name="click3" onclick="update_row(\''.$row['ID'].'\',\''.$row['code'].'\',\''.$row['name'].'\',\''.$row['price'].'\')" value="Save"></div>';
                        echo '</li>';
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";
                ?>
            </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```